# Joint Probability Distribution in Python

Tags: python, probability

I have two discrete random variables. Lets say A and B each of size Nx1. Lets say A has m unique values and B has n unique values. I want to find a mxn matrix of their frequencies or probability distribution. Later, I want to plot this matrix to show the distribution.

I want to do this in python. I am relatively new in the language and I wanted to know if there is a function that can help do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: How are you describing the `A` and `B` probability distributions? If you're using something like a numpy array, finding the combined distribution is simply a matter of applying the broadcasting rules to multiplication. If you're using more primitive Python types (like lists or dictionaries) only a little more work is required, probably in a list or dictionary comprehension.

Comment: I have read the values from a tsv file using pandas. They are stored as series. But then can be put into numpy array. What do you mean by broadcasting rules to multiplication?

Answer (score 2):

To make a `n` by `m` matrix in `numpy`, you can multiply two arrays of appropriate shape. If array `x` is `n` by `1` and array `y` is `1` by `m`, their product `x * y` will be `n` by `m`.

Here's an example of how you can go about this with data that is initially one dimensional (I'm using random values, which should really be normalized if it's a probability distribution, but for the example it doesn't matter):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random(5)          # n values
>>> print(a)
[ 0.884703    0.78476467  0.26084923  0.82228242  0.48263909]
>>> b = np.random.random(8)          # m values
>>> print(b)
[ 0.53982228  0.59494659  0.92725768  0.03275801  0.39763316  0.72638816
  0.37634726  0.85483384]
>>> matrix = a[:,None] * b[None,:]   # n by m matrix
>>> print(matrix)
[[ 0.47758239  0.52635103  0.82034765  0.02898111  0.35178725  0.64263778
   0.33295555  0.75627406]
 [ 0.42363345  0.46689307  0.72767907  0.02570733  0.31204846  0.57004376
   0.29534404  0.6708434 ]
 [ 0.14081223  0.15519136  0.24187445  0.0085449   0.10372231  0.18947779
   0.0981699   0.22298275]
 [ 0.44388637  0.48921412  0.76246768  0.02693634  0.32696676  0.59729621
   0.30946374  0.70291484]
 [ 0.26053933  0.28714448  0.4475308   0.0158103   0.19191331  0.35058332
   0.1816399   0.41257622]]
```

The slices with `None` tell numpy to add an extra dimension to each array before performing the multiplication.